# Cannot shift row to bottom

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want this part (demo [HERE](http://jsbin.com/efoviz/3/edit))

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="hundred">Hello</div>
</div>
```

To be all the way at the bottom.

I've tried clearing and the only thing that works is `margin-top` at a crazy px amount of 500px+. Otherwise it won't even move. Could someone explain why this is happening exactly?

EDIT: In the code, the part I need help with is this one

```
 <div class="row" style="position: relative; margin-top: 625px">
       <div class="hundred">Hello</div>
    </div>
```

If you take out `margin-top: 625px` the div goes up - how do I make it stay without `margin-top` set at such a crazy amount?

I am NOT looking for a footer guys - These boxes serve another purpose - I just want to make another row basically - without having the bottom overlap the previous row.

Comment: By all means set up a `jsbin` or a `jsfiddle`. Please post a simplified version here so that the question makes sense when the fiddle has gone.

Comment: The JSBIN IS there - you don't see the link up top?

Comment: yes I do, but I don't see any code _here_

Comment: Maybe your browser is funky - The link works on my end. If it still doesn't work for YOU - Here is the link http://jsbin.com/efoviz/3/edit

Comment: Maybe you just haven't understood: you should post your code (or a version of it) here, on this site. This ensures that at some point in the future your question still makes sense, even if the link to another site no longer works.

Comment: It's too much code to post here - it easier to have a demo. And I would update it if it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

It is a difficult problem because there is no such thing as a "bottom". The webpage is infinitely tall.

The only reliable way is to use JavaScript, and it's difficult especially on touchscreen browsers.

Instead you should try to design your page so that you do not need to put something at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a clear:both and overflow:hidden to the .row selector. If you want it right at the bottom then you have to use position:absolute; bottom: 0

Answer (score 0):

The below `css` will always keeps footer at the bottom.  In your case, increase the height of the `container`.

The reason why `margin-top` worked is you're going beyond the specified height.

```
<div class="row" id="footer">
       <div class="hundred">Hello</div>
</div>
```

For my convenience I've used `id` selector.

```
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width:100%;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsbin.com/asurow/1/edit) in JSBin for reference.
Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do it by wrapping content and bottom section into two divs like

**html**

```
  <div id="wrap">
    <div class="container">    
      <div class="row">
        <div class="hundred"></div>
      </div>
    </div>     
  </div>
  <div id="bottom">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="hundred">Hello</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**css** ( *chnages* )

```
html {
    height:100%;
}
body {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
}
#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -150px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/uhonus/1/edit)

Hope this helps